# How to make the pdf file that inserted stayed the position I give?

Tags: graphics, floats, wolfram-mathematica

I'd like to typeset the *Mathematica* code.My solution is

> [image]

Select it (by clicking on the right square bracket `]`). Then, following the menu's `File>Save Selection As...` and saving as a PDF produces the PDF output:

So I achieve a pdf file. Then I insert in my Latex document.

**My sample code:**

```
\documentclass[b5paper,UTF8]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}                
\usepackage{geometry}               
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Iteration Order}
Consider the following matrix :

\begin{figure}[h]
 \fbox{\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{IO1.pdf}}
\end{figure}

 We can use a Table expression to create a copy of the matrix by iterating over all
 of its elements:

\begin{figure}[h]
 \fbox{\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{IO2.pdf}}
\end{figure}

 This identity operation is uninteresting, but we can transform the array by swapping
 the order of the iteration variables. For example, we can swap i and j iterators.
 This amounts to swapping the level 1 and level 2 indices and their corresponding 
 elements:

\end{document}
```

However, the file became as shown below:

> [image]

Namely, `the pdf file that inserted staying other position`.

So my question is:

- 1. how to make the PDf file stayed the position that I give?
- 2. Is it possible to zip the size of the PDF file that I insert to the Latex document?

Comment: If you don't want things to float, don't use a floating environment such as `figure`.

Comment: @PeterGrill,OK, I got it, I delete rhis enviroment :`figure`,it work normally:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want things to float, don't use a floating environment such as `figure`.